# Operator and method chaining in ruby

Tags: ruby

I came across some results in a program I was writing that confused me.  It is my understanding parens are not normally needed (i.e. `obj.method1.method2` is as good as `(obj.method1).method2`).  In addition all operators are really method calls so I expected them to behave similarly.

So imagine my surprise that `"S"+"R".downcase` resulted in `Sr` as did `"S".+"R".downcase` however `"S".send(:+, "R").downcase` finally gave me the expected output `sr`

Is this because the operator shortcuts are treated differently or is there some other mechanic at work here that I am missing?

---

Edit:  The question isn't about the order of operations that resulted in the answer, that's obvious.  The question was WHY the expression was resolved in that order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.` has higher precedence than `+` and is evaluated first. `("S"+"R").downcase` works too.

Comment: No `"S"+"R".downcase` in not equal to `"S".+"R".downcase` cause `"R".downcase` is an argument.

Comment: I assume that all (arithmetic?) operators share this lower precedence?

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect how this is parsed with Ripper, if you have Ruby >= 1.9:

```
require 'ripper'
require 'pp'

src = '"A"+"B".downcase'
pp Ripper::SexpBuilder.new(src).parse
```

You will see that the method call (from the '.') has a higher precedence than the binary plus:

```
[:program,
 [:stmts_add,
  [:stmts_new],
  [:binary,
   [:string_literal,
    [:string_add, [:string_content], [:@tstring_content, "A", [1, 1]]]],
   :+,
   [:call,
    [:string_literal,
     [:string_add, [:string_content], [:@tstring_content, "B", [1, 5]]]],
    :".",
    [:@ident, "downcase", [1, 8]]]]]]
```

The precedence of operators can also be directly derived from Ruby's [parse.y](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y), if you are familiar with bison/yacc.